# Selenium timeoutexception error in one of the iterations

Tags: python, selenium

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) #wait 20s to let webpage load

driver.get('https://beta.clinicaltrials.gov/') #getting website url

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)

country = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/ctg-home/div/div[2]/ctg-advanced-search-home/div[2]/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/div[3]/ctg-location-search-input/form/div[2]/div/label')))
country.click()

searchBar = driver.find_element("id",'location-input')
searchBar.send_keys("Singapore") #input country name into searchBar

search_dropdown = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-option-14"]/span'))) #wait till xpath is visible
search_dropdown.click()


search_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/ctg-home/div/div[2]/ctg-advanced-search-home/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button')))
search_button.click()


#finding filter button for recruiting status
filter_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter-button-statusGroup"]')))
filter_button.click()

#clicking on 'recruiting' status
recruiting = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="adv-check-status"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/label')))
recruiting.click()

#scraping each clinical trial details
clinical_trial = {} #empty dict to store details
name_list = []
phone_list = []
email_list = []
enrollment = []
condition_list = []

#loop to go through all the clinical trials in the search page (10 per page)
for i in range(1,11):
    time.sleep(2) #wait 2s to let page load
    xpath = '//*[@id="content"]/div/ctg-search-results/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ctg-search-hit-card[{}]/div/header/a'.format(i)
    trials = driver.find_element("xpath", xpath)
    trials.click()
    #time.sleep(5) #wait 5s to let page load
    
    #getting contact person name
    name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="studyDetailsInfo"]/ctg-study-info/div/ctg-study-info-view/div/div[2]/ctg-study-contacts-and-locations/div/div/div/ctg-study-contact-info/p[1]/span')))
    name_list.append(name.text) #adding each name to the list
    
    #phone number of contact person
    phone = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="studyDetailsInfo"]/ctg-study-info/div/ctg-study-info-view/div/div[2]/ctg-study-contacts-and-locations/div/div/div/ctg-study-contact-info/p[2]/span')))
    phone_list.append(phone.text) #adding each phone number to the list
    
    #email of contact person
    email = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="studyDetailsInfo"]/ctg-study-info/div/ctg-study-info-view/div/div[2]/ctg-study-contacts-and-locations/div/div/div/ctg-study-contact-info/p[3]/ctg-study-contact-email/span/a')))
    email_list.append(email.text) #adding each email address to the list
    
    #number of enrollment
    enrollment_num = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="studyDetailsInfo"]/ctg-study-info/div/ctg-study-info-view/div/div[1]/ctg-study-overview/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]')))
    enrollment.append(enrollment_num.text) #adding each enrollment number to the list
    
    #condition of study
    conditions = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="studyDetailsInfo"]/ctg-study-info/div/ctg-study-info-view/div/div[1]/ctg-study-overview/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')))
    condition_list.append(conditions.text) #adding conditions of the study to list
    
    driver.back() #return to search page


#adding all the different list details to the contact_details dict
clinical_trial["name"] = name_list
clinical_trial["phone_num"] = phone_list
clinical_trial["email_address"] = email_list
clinical_trial["Enrollment"] = enrollment
clinical_trial["Conditions"] = condition_list
```

I am having an issue with selenium somehow not finding the xpath for `enrollment_num` in the loop. The loop runs through the 10 clickable links on the webpage, however it gives a `TimeoutException` error at the 9th link. Why is that so? When i change the loop to iterate through 8 links instead of the usual 10 links, it works fine. Its just that one link which creates the error.

Comment: i updated my response. see below. the difference is tiny and hard to spot.
i use notepad++ with the compare plugin to compare long strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page number 9 is different from all the other pages. The difference is hard to spot. Tipp: to compare strings i use Notepad++ with the compare plugin.
This page does not have these 2 elements:

1. `enrollment_num =...ctg-study-overview/div[3]/div[2]/di...'`

   here it is:

   `enrollment_num =...ctg-study-overview/div[2]/div[2]/di...`
2. `conditions = ...ctg-study-overview/div[3]/di...`

   here it is:

   `...ctg-study-overview/div[2]/di...`

This is why it runs into a timeout. You could build a try:except:else around these to avoid the program from crashing. Below a quick fix. Of course you should tidy it up. I hope this helps.

```
# number of enrollment
try:
    enrollment_num = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                                  '//*[@id="studyDetailsInfo"]/ctg-study-info/div/ctg-study-info-view/div/div[1]/ctg-study-overview/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]')))
    enrollment.append(enrollment_num.text)  # adding each enrollment number to the list

except:
    print("enrollement div[3] but div[2]")
    enrollment_num = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                                  '//*[@id="studyDetailsInfo"]/ctg-study-info/div/ctg-study-info-view/div/div[1]/ctg-study-overview/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]')))
    enrollment.append(enrollment_num.text)  # adding each enrollment number to the list
else:
    pass


# condition of study
try:
    conditions = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                              '//*[@id="studyDetailsInfo"]/ctg-study-info/div/ctg-study-info-view/div/div[1]/ctg-study-overview/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')))
    condition_list.append(conditions.text)  # adding conditions of the study to list
except:
    print("condition_list non div[3] but div[2]")
    conditions = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                              '//*[@id="studyDetailsInfo"]/ctg-study-info/div/ctg-study-info-view/div/div[1]/ctg-study-overview/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')))
    condition_list.append(conditions.text)  # adding conditions of the study to list
else:
    pass
```

Comment: thats strange because i checked the xpath and they are the same? or am i checking the wrong one?

Comment: i can imagine that the search By.XPATH can be vulnerable to unpredictable changes on the open page like mobile view or anything. Maybe try to replace By.XPATH with By.CSSELECTOR and try to find a closer ID like [@id="estimatedEnrollmentAccordion"]

Comment: @tetrisprogramming Add `enrollment.append(None)` to the end of both exception blocks to prevent mixing data from other pages.

Comment: it worked and wow i just double checked the xpath and they are indeed different! Thank you so much!

Comment: hi there to add on, i have another minor issue which im not quite understanding. So for page number 9, i notice that it takes much longer to scrape as compared to the other pages. Why is that so? like for the other pages, it happens almost instantly while for page 9 in particular it takes about 30s and more to scrape the info.

Comment: This is because of our try: conditions = wait.until() combination.
On page 9 he first trys to find the non existing condition untin wailt.until()returns an error (which is about 20 seconds). Only from that moment on he goes to the except block where the correct path is provided.
You could try to remove the wait.until for the try/except blocks.